# Overriding the constraint type of the generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints, overriding

I have created a generic type helper called `DataType`, which accepts a parameter T that is constrained to the `keyof MyObject` type. If the key is present in `MyObject`,`DataType` will return the property type of `MyObject`; otherwise, it will return T itself.

```
interface MyObject {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
}
export type DataType<T extends keyof MyObject> = T extends keyof MyObject
  ?  MyObject[T] 
  : T;
```

Now if I pass any key of `MyObject`, it will return the corresponding type:

```
type StrType=DataType<'foo'>; // data type is string
```

But if I pass a data type other than a string to this helper, I am getting `Type 'type' does not satisfy the constraint '"foo"'`:

```
type numType=DataType<number>;
```

How to not constrain the type but still have IntelliSense prompt for the key of `MyObject`?

Comment: What is `LiteralUnion` supposed to be?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code so it's a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE... without undefined/undeclared values or types.

Comment: @AlexWayne I removed `LiteralUnion` and simplified the question to make it easier to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbKYoW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I misisng?

Comment: @jcalz Yes it does. Would it be possible for you to provide an explanation as an answer?  I will set it as the accepted answer so it may help others. Thank you.

Comment: I am writing up an answer now; could you [edit] the question so it clearly asks about how to not constrain the type but still have IntelliSense prompting for `keyof MyObject`?  Right now that information is only in the comments, but it belongs in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T`; it can be anything, even [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  That can be accomplished by just leaving it as `type DataType<T> = ...` without a constraint on the `T`.

```
interface MyObject {
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
}

type DataType<T> =
  T extends keyof MyObject ? MyObject[T] : T;

type StrType = DataType<'foo'>; // string
type NumType = DataType<number>; // number
```

But if you do that, you will lose IntelliSense hints suggesting the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) members of `keyof MyObject`:

```
// type BooType = DataType<'⃒'> 
// ----------------------> ^^ <---
// IntelliSense prompts here with NOTHING
```

---

So what you're looking for is a type which is equivalent to `unknown`, but has some "memory" of `keyof MyObject` that IntelliSense can use.

You might think of using [the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `keyof MyObject | unknown`, but unfortunately `unknown` eagerly *absorbs* other types in unions.  So `keyof MyObject | unknown` becomes `unknown` before IntelliSense has a chance to do anything.

Luckily, there is another type which is similar in spirit to `unknown`: the union `{} | null | undefined`.  The so-called empty object type `{}` actually accepts any non-nullish type whatsoever, even primitives like `string` (that's because `string` has apparent members like `"length"` and `"toUpperCase"`, so `string` is a subtype of `{length: number, toUpperCase(): string}`, which is a subtype of `{}`).  The only values not assignable to `{}` are `null` and `undefined`.  So the union `{} | null | undefined` is essentially the same as `unknown`.  There are some minor differences, but [you are even allowed to assign `unknown` to `{} | null | undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing).

One "minor" difference is that `{} | null | undefined` will not eagerly absorb string literals in unions.  So the union `keyof MyObject | {} | null | undefined` stays unreduced, and so `keyof MyObject` is still available for IntelliSense to act on:

```
type DataType<T extends (keyof MyObject | {} | null | undefined)> =
  T extends keyof MyObject ? MyObject[T] : T;

type StrType = DataType<'foo'>; // string
type NumType = DataType<number>; // number       

// type BooType = DataType<'⃒'> 
// ----------------------> ^^ <---
// IntelliSense prompts here with
//     bar
//     foo    
type BooType = DataType<'bar'> // boolean
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=false&ts=4.9.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZZGAexoC5kBnMKUAcwG4Krs4pG2OgBsIcEN3IBfChQgAPAA40oRMOkUoAInDBwAKhogAefcgWQQAEybIAFAGsI6GjDRY8BIgB9kAV2sIGFAIK2RfED9hYXCSKQBKAD5kAF4eZDMLCGtbJxc3DBx8QmQAfncirwBtfQBdZEZ9SQp1TWQAZVZDNpTkHT1ukwByWhohxM5kAHop5lYOFqNkADk-AFtB1L7dAyNjSLXsaAnp2YOjqAoZ5FaUACE6Td7+3c1jIcAlgnHkK9mAWgBgKBwJBf2SAD1wchjIDfsgAJLgCDRYDtbJMFCKKA0NaKMC2AAW0BQAHdgGACXCqMhALwbgHJd5B8S7ka7U+nUOiyci3ZAPGhPbYDPZDJnfa5CGiicRcoA)

Answer (score 0):

If `T` can be any type, just remove the constraint:

```
export type DataType<T> = T extends keyof MyObject
  ?  MyObject[T] 
  : T;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChlkYB7KgLmQGcwpQBzAblIF9SIAPAA5UoRMOgEoAInDBwAKuIgAeOQD5kAXmRzk-SCAAmDZAGsI6KjDRY8BMOWQB+Chhz5CAbTkBdZA-pynKRiEsgAyswKEhrSslHKAOTUVAmq7MgA9BnIBjJwyCEowMZMLCCspMGKyCAArgC28TF58Up19djQaUA)

Comment: The purpose of constraint is to have the Intellisense feature of the IDE, so that I can know which keys are available to select. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: That's not what type constraints are meant for. The language spec and compiler exist independently of any IDE features. I don't know of a way to guide autocompletion though.